# How can I change the REFERENCE in a FOREIGN KEY?

Tags: mariadb, foreign-key, referential-integrity

After renaming some tables I get the following error:

```
MariaDB [testdb]> INSERT INTO user_events (date, uid, operation, info) VALUES('2022-09-15','xyz','create',NULL);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails `testdb`.`user_events`, CONSTRAINT `user_events_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `associations` (`uid`))
```

The reason is that the table `associations` in `REFERENCES` needs to be changed to `users`.

What is the easiest way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow a three step process.

`1. Identify the foreign keys names from the tables`

In your example `show create table user_events` would give the foreign key name .

You can find al the foreign key names for a schema using below query:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME,TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
AND information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'world';
```

`2. Drop the foreign key constraint`

If your tables engine are [Innodb](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) use following query to drop the foreign key:

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES user_events WRITE;
ALTER TABLE user_events DROP FOREIGN KEY user_events_ibfk_1;
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

`3. Recreate the foreign key constraint`

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES user_events WRITE;
ALTER TABLE user_events  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_events_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `users` (`uid`);
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

*Note*. Step 2 and 3 can be combined into one query but the foreign key name must be different from the dropped one

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES user_events WRITE;
ALTER TABLE user_events 
DROP FOREIGN KEY user_events_ibfk_1,
ADD CONSTRAINT `user_events_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `users` (`uid`));
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Response to Rick comment

> I doubt if the LOCK/UNLOCKs are necessary. Ergest, do you know that
> they are needed?

From the docs [Online DDL Limitations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-limitations.html)

> When running an in-place online DDL operation, the thread that runs
> the ALTER TABLE statement applies an online log of DML operations that
> were run concurrently on the same table from other connection threads.
> When the DML operations are applied, it is possible to encounter a
> duplicate key entry error (ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry), even
> if the duplicate entry is only temporary and would be reverted by a
> later entry in the online log.

The error faced without locking the table (not always) , most of the time happens on big tables which will result on the failure of the alter statement :

> Error 1062: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL Statement: ALTER
> TABLE user_events
> DROP FOREIGN KEY user_events_ibfk_1,
> ADD CONSTRAINT `user_events_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `users`
> (`uid`);

To prevent this use proper lock syntax as described above

Comment: I doubt if the LOCK/UNLOCKs are necessary.  Ergest, do you know that they are needed?

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me, although there is a typo in step 3, namely an extra ')' at the end of the line.